# Can't pass a local variable from a thread

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, parameter-passing

I made a thread *thread1* which creates another thread *thread2*. When I try to pass the value of *fd* (fd declared inside *thread2*) using pthread_exit from *thread2* to *thread1* I get a garbage value in *retval*. But when I declare fd as a global variable I get correct value in *retval*. I got an answer that this is because the thread is finished so it can't pass the value. But in case of *functions*, a local variable's scope is also limited inside the function and they do return values. So why can't a thread do that?

Here is the code that I tried:

```
    void *thread2(void *message)
    {
        int fd;
        void *retval;
        fd=open(message,O_RDWR);
        printf("message is - %s",(char *)message);
        pthread_exit(&fd);
    }
    void *thread1(void *message)
    {
        void *retval;
        pthread_t *tid2;
        tido=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        pthread_create(tid2,NULL,thread2,message);
        pthread_join(*tid2,&retval);
        printf("fd in write is-%d\n",*(int *)retval);
        pthread_exit(&retval);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... your `int fd` is an automatic variable (which we may assume is on the stack), so is out of scope when `thread2()` returns, so passing a pointer to `fd` out of the function is probably going to lead to disappointment.

A function can return the value of an automatic (aka local) variable.  What it cannot do is return the address of one (not and work, anyway).

What you could do is construct a struct to pass into `thread2()`, to carry parameters in and results back.